# http get from jsp and resolve status code

Tags: java, spring, http, jsp, servlets

I need to send http request to certain URL via jsp (by clicking on a link / button). Depending on the http response status code I need to generate corresponding output in the jsp (200 - action OK, 404 - unknown action etc, the content of the URL is irrelevant). Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

I am using Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First send your request to a servlet using AJAX and call the url that you want from the servlet.From that url response you can use `int status = response.getStatus();` on the HttpServletResponse object in your servlet and based on the `int` value that you get you can write your if else statements and use `PrintWriter`'s `println` method to send response/text to the ajax call on your jsp and use it wherever you want in that jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery and make an ajax call using its ajax method and use it success/error callback methods to get textStatus